# Can you create a package, that has imports inside?

Tags: java, import, package

Can you make a package, that has imports like Javafx imports and then use these imports when importing the package to a java file?

Comment: Hello GmP and welcome!
Could you be more specific to what you mean by providing some snippets of code? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by a package that has imports?

Comment: not sure if I do understand, but are you aware that the `import` statement is just importing the given namespace? In other words, instead of having to write `java.time.LocalDateTime` every time, you can just write `LocalDateTime` if you have an `import java.time.LocalDateTime;` (or `import java.time.*;`)

Comment: No, this is not possible. Java doesn't have transitive imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you asked if you can import a class that already has some imports and if you can use them without import again in your class. You have to understand what is package and what are imports for.

From **Java Documentation**

A **package** is a grouping of related types providing access protection and name space management. Note that types refers to classes, interfaces, enumerations, and annotation types.

Now about import statements:

Imports are only tells the compiler where to look for symbols/classes used in your class. For example, the Date class.

```
Date myDate = new Date();
```

Compiler needs to know where to look for the Date.class (e.g **java.util.Date** or **java.sql.Date**).

So anytime you use the Date in your class you have to import the package of Date.class. No matter if you extend another class that use the java.util.Date or java.sql.Date, you have to import this package again.

Comment: "...have to import the package..." or use the fully qualified name like in `java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();`